# How to implement CISC Pipelined CPU right?

Tags: assembly, cpu, pipeline, cpu-architecture, risc

I'm working on the project for my graduation in college. I already did one pipelined CPU and simulated it in Logisim program for one of my courses, but now I need to flash CPU to my FPGA and write game for this CPU also. So I thought to improve my architecture and also I altered some functions, because didn't really knew how it should work. The problem is with Memory accessing, on the first picture you can see my first CPU. Logic was: Read opcode->decode and prepare operands->Read memory if needed->Check if JMP(CJE,CJNE...)->Arithmetic and logic calculations->Write answer to register or to memory (I delayed here for 1 clock all pipeline if needed for not to collide with read memory operations - Memory Hazard avoiding).

[image: Pipe1]

[image: CPU Diagram]

Now I want to insert some graphics for my game and added one more segment that will cooperate with PPU(Picture Processing Unit).

[image: Pipe2]

Also, I saw a lot of examples in the Internet that put Memory segment after Execution segment and that is not understandable for me. How I can implement opcode like ADD A, MEM if I need to read the MEM variable form Memory and then to add it to A? Or I'm missing something? Can you, please, help me with that?

Comment: Pipeline is **much** easier to implement with RISC isa where all memory accesses are either load or store. Instructions like `ADD A, MEM` are forbidden in this model.  They must be split in two instructions (or uops).

Comment: @AlainMerigot: or you implement it like 486 / Pentium, and memory-source instructions take multiple cycles.  (e.g. https://agner.org/optimize/ has P5 Pentium instruction timings.  `add reg, [mem]` takes 2 cycles, and is pairable in either pipe.  I don't think splitting internally into uops is an accurate description of how P5 pentium handles memory-source or memory-dest instructions, that came later in P6 to enable out-of-order exec).  But when designing an ISA from scratch, it would be nearly pointless to make it CISC but then make only the RISC subset of it pipeline fully efficiently.

Comment: But yes, it's obviously much harder and more complex.  You might put a load stage before exec, and a store stage after?  But then you have to detect memory dependency hazards for store-forwarding or stalling.  In-order Atom does do LEA on its AGUs, in a stage before normal exec, so probably it has actual memory access there, too.  Maybe you could have that pre-exec memory access also write into the store buffer for store or RMW instructions, so later loads will see that there's a store or pending store.  Or just don't let the next instruction start for 3 cycles after a RMW, like P5 Pentium!

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you for your answer. I think I will save the memory reading before execution and in WB stage will make Memory hazard unit for checking collisions. It will not stall pipeline every time I need to write to memory. but only if there is another reading operations happens.